# PID: 12181 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I am working on shopping application, If I add one product to cart then add another product to cart, and if I again add first product to cart two products with same name were added to cart, I am trying to modify same product by adding quantity and rate of new product to original.

```
    if (allselectedVegetables.size == 0) {
        allselectedVegetables.add(selectedVegetable)
    } else {
        for (it in allselectedVegetables) {

            if (it.name.equals(selectedVegetable.name)) {
                //Item Already present

                if (selectedVegetable.radioTypeOfWeightstring.equals(Const.QUANTITY)) {

                    selectedVegetable.quantity =
                        (selectedVegetable.quantity.toInt() + it.quantity.toInt()).toString()
                } else {
                    // Item KG
                    selectedVegetable.weight =
                        (selectedVegetable.weight.toInt() + it.weight.toInt()).toString()
                }


                val total =
                    (selectedVegetable.totalAmount.toDouble()) + (it.totalAmount.toDouble())
                selectedVegetable.totalAmount = total.toString()

                allselectedVegetables.add(selectedVegetable)


            } else {
                allselectedVegetables.add(selectedVegetable)

            }
        }
```

I am getting ConcurrentModificationException, Please help me out with code snippet

Comment: It is not permissible for a thread to modify a Collection when some other thread is iterating over it.This is because the result of the iteration becomes undefined with it.

Comment: As Darwin said, you are trying to modify the collection whilst another thread is reading/writing to it. There are a few possible solutions; use a concurrent collection (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html), or create a lock that will not allow read/write of the collection if another thread is writing to said collection.